# Drop Vertical Mega Menu outside <aside> tag to right

Tags: html, css, adminlte

I'm using `AdminLTE3` template along with code I found on [codepen to create a vertical Mega Menu](https://codepen.io/JJohn_J/pen/KdaPmq).

Issue I'm facing right now is can be seen in the picture below[image]

Is it possible to drop the submenu outside the `navbar` for better view.

```
<aside
  class="main-sidebar sidebar-primary elevation-4"
  style="background-color: #f2f2f2"
>
  <a [routerLink]="['home']" class="brand-link bg-blue">
      <img
        src="../../assets/LLlogo.png"
        alt="AdminLTE Logo"
        class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3"
        style="opacity: 0.8"
      />
      <span class="brand-text font-weight-light" style="color: black"
        >LD</span
      >
    </a>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <nav class="mt-2">
<ul
          class="menu nav nav-pills nav-sidebar nav-child-indent flex-column"
          data-widget="treeview"
          role="menu"
          data-accordion="false"
        >
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#">MEGA MENU 1</a>

            <div class="megadrop">
              <div class="col">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <ul>
                  <li ><a href="#">Sub-menu 1</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Sub-menu 2</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Sub-menu 3</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">MEGA MENU 2</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">MEGA MENU 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">MEGA MENU 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
</aside>
```

CSS- I'm using is similar to one in `codepen link` above.

Admin LTE documentation could be found [here](https://adminlte.io/docs/3.0/components/main-sidebar.html)

Let me know if any additional information is required

I'm trying to achieve this kind of structure like overlay
[image: overlay]

As this dropdown is covering over the content, I'm looking for similar kind of structure

Comment: You just want the fly-out menu to extend over the main content area? Your demo seems to be doing that.

Comment: Yes! That's what i'm trying to achieve, yes somewhat its doing that but I want to extend it oustide the container its in for better view